# How do you return non-copyable types?

Tags: function, rust

I am trying to understand how you return non-primitives (i.e. types that do not implement `Copy`). If you return something like a `i32`, then the function creates a new value in memory with a copy of the return value, so it can be used outside the scope of the function. But if you return a type that doesn't implement `Copy`, it does not do this, and you get ownership errors.

I have tried using `Box` to create values on the heap so that the caller can take ownership of the return value, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Perhaps I am approaching this in the wrong manner by using the same coding style that I use in C# or other languages, where functions return values, rather than passing in an object reference as a parameter and mutating it, so that you can easily indicate ownership in Rust.

The following code examples fails compilation. I believe the issue is only within the iterator closure, but I have included the entire function just in case I am not seeing something.

```
pub fn get_files(path: &Path) -> Vec<&Path> { 
      let contents = fs::walk_dir(path); 

      match contents { 
          Ok(c) => c.filter_map(|i| { match i { 
                  Ok(d) => {  
                      let val = d.path(); 
                      let p = val.as_path(); 
                      Some(p) 
                  }, 
                  Err(_) => None } }) 
              .collect(), 
          Err(e) => panic!("An error occurred getting files from {:?}: {}", pa
    th, e) 
      } 
 }
```

The compiler gives the following error (I have removed all the line numbers and extraneous text):

```
error: `val` does not live long enough
                     let p = val.as_path();
                                            ^~~
in expansion of closure expansion
expansion site
reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block...
...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement
                     let val = d.path();
                     let p = val.as_path();
                     Some(p)
                 },
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You return a value by... well *returning it*. However, your signature shows that you are trying to return a **reference to a value**. You can't do that when the object will be dropped at the end of the block because the reference would become invalid.

In your case, I'd probably write something like

```
#![feature(fs_walk)]

use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn get_files(path: &Path) -> Vec<PathBuf> { 
    let contents = fs::walk_dir(path).unwrap(); 
    contents.filter_map(|i| {
        i.ok().map(|p| p.path())
    }).collect()
}

fn main() {
    for f in get_files(Path::new("/etc")) {
        println!("{:?}", f);
    }
}
```

The main thing is that the function returns a `Vec<PathBuf>` — a collection of a type that *owns* the path, and are more than just references into someone else's memory.

In your code, you do `let p = val.as_path()`. Here, `val` is a [`PathBuf`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html). Then you call `as_path`, which is defined as: `fn as_path(&self) -> &Path`. This means that given a reference to a `PathBuf`, you can get a reference to a `Path` *that will live as long as the `PathBuf` will*. However, you are trying to keep that reference around longer than `vec` will exist, as it will be dropped at the end of the iteration.

Comment: To complement the answer: `PathBuf` is to `&Path` what `String` is to `&str`. If you grasp the `String`/`&str` dichotomy, this may help you understand why returning the `PathBuf` is the right thing here.

Comment: Great point, @mdup! Rust has lots of these paired owned / borrowed types. `Vec<T>` and `&[T]` is another common one you will see quickly when starting Rust.

Answer (score 3):

**How do you return non-copyable types?**

By value.

```
fn make() -> String { "Hello, World!".into() }
```

---

There is a disconnect between:

- the language semantics
- the implementation details

Semantically, returning by value is *moving* the object, not copying it. In Rust, any object is movable and, optionally, may also be Clonable (implement `Clone`) and Copyable (implement `Clone` and `Copy`).

That the implementation of copying or moving uses a `memcpy` under the hood is a detail that does not affect the semantics, only performance. Furthermore, this being an implementation detail means that it can be optimized away without affecting the semantics, which the optimizer will try very hard to do.

---

As for your particular code, you have a lifetime issue. You cannot return a reference to a value if said reference may outlive the value (for then, what would it reference?).

The simple fix is to return the value itself: `Vec<PathBuf>`. As mentioned, it will *move* the paths, not copy them.

Comment: I don't believe you can return a `Path` in this case. The `walk_dir` iterator owns a `PathBuf` and can transfer it via `path()`, but `Path` is a reference, much like `str`, and is usually used as `&Path`. You can't have a `Vec<str>`, so I don't think you can have a `Vec<Path>`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: That's what the doc suggests, indeed! (I've never used it personally).

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm setting a bad example by using it in my code; it's technically an [unstable API](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.walk_dir.html).

Comment: @CalMlynarczyk: unstable does not mean bad! It just means subject to arbitrary changes :)